# Zeros of hypergeometric functions with complex variables

Tags: cv.complex-variables, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Let $z$ be a complex number and let $a,b,c > 0$. I would like to know the zeros of the following hypergeometric function:
$$_{2}F_{1} (a,b; c :z  )=\sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty} \frac{(a)_{k}(b)_{k}}{(c)_{k}} \frac{z^{k}}{k!}$$
i.e, i want to identify the set $A$ such $_{2}F_{1} (a,b; c :z  )=0$ for all $z \in A$. For instance, consider $t$ as real number where $_{2}F_{1} (a,b; c :t  )=0$, it is obvious in that case that $t$ would be a negative real number. Is there a paper or an article or a suggestion salving that problem

Comment: The radius of convergence is $1$.  (Unless the series terminates, say $a=-n$ as in Carlo's answer.)  If you consider analytic continuation (as suggested by Alexandre) it could be a multivalued function.  And you could have a zero which is real and ${} > 1$.

Comment: no a is strictly positive

Answer (score 4):

Much of the literature addresses the case that $a=-n$ is a negative integer, see [Real zeros of $2F1$ hypergeometric polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.4771) (2013) and [Zeros of the hypergeometric polynomial $F(-n,b;c;z)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0708) (2008). Even that case has not been fully solved...

Answer (score 4):

The hypergeometric function is not a function in the usual meaning of this word: it is multivalued. For real parameters $a,b,c$, the question about
real zeros of real branches was investigated by Klein,

Uber die Nullstellen der hypergeometrischen Reihe, Math.
Ann., 37 (1890) 573-590.

He determined exactly, how many zeros are there on the intervals $(0,1)$,
$(1,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$. Later A. Hurwitz gave simpler proofs,
and E. van Vleck generalized Klein's result to complex zeros:

Van Vleck, Edward B. A determination of the number of real and imaginary roots of the hypergeometric series. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 3 (1902), no. 1, 110–131.

For complex parameters, only partial results are available.