# On the solutions of $_2F_1(\alpha, \beta; \gamma, z) = \Lambda$

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, hypergeometric-functions, zeroes

**More General Question**

Let
$$F(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(\alpha)_n(\beta)_n}{(\gamma)_nn!}z^n, \quad |z| < 1, \quad (x)_n = x(x+1)...(x+n-1), \quad (x)_0 = 1$$
be the usual Gauss hypergeometric function, extended holomorphically on $\mathbb C \setminus [1,+\infty)$, which solves the homogeneous hypergeometric ODE
$$z(1-z)w''(z) + (\gamma - (\alpha + \beta + 1)z)w'(z) - \alpha \beta w(z) = 0, \quad 0 \leq z < 1$$
Here, I assume that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are real parameters for which $\gamma$ and $\gamma - \alpha - \beta$ are not integers.

The zeros of $F(\alpha,\beta;\gamma,z)$ on $(0,1)$, $(-\infty,0)$ and the half-planes can be counted (e.g. see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/421105/130116) for early references which use long geometric arguments or this [shorter proof](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01433471.pdf) of Runckel).

I'm interested in counting the zeros on $(0,1)$, $(-\infty,0)$ and the half-planes of
$$F(\alpha,\beta;\gamma,z) - \Lambda$$
for some $\Lambda \in \mathbb R$. This function solves the inhomogeneous hypergeometric ODE with a constant forcing term.

In Bateman, "Higher Transcendental Functions", Vol.1, Ch. 2.7.4, it is stated that such an equation has only finitely many solutions. The case $\Lambda = 0$ is well-known but have the other cases been studied ?

---

**Original Question**

Let
$$F(z) = \frac{1}{\alpha\beta}F(\alpha,\beta;\gamma,z)-\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}+1$$
This function arises as a regular solution of the inhomogeneous problem
$$z(1-z)w''(z) + (\gamma - (\alpha + \beta + 1)z)w'(z) - \alpha \beta w(z) = 1-\frac{1}{\alpha \beta}, \quad 0 \leq z < 1$$
with boundary condition $w(0) = 1$.

Assume that $\gamma > 1$ and $\alpha \beta > 1$. An argument by contradiction, based on the ODE, shows that this solution is strictly increasing on $[0,1)$, but such an argument does not extend to the complex plane.

Is it possible to infer anything on the non-real zeros of $F(z)$ from the zeros of some hypergeometric function, say $F(\alpha,\beta;\gamma,z)$ or $F(\alpha+1,\beta+1;\gamma+1,z)$ ? For example, we can assume that we use a choice of parameters for which all their zeros are located on $(-\infty,0)$.

I was thinking of either applying Rouché Theorem or the Lemma 1 from Runckel's paper. Both are tedious because they require finding an appropriate function.

I'm mostly interested in zeros located in the ball $B_{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{1}{2})$, with the choice of parameters $(\alpha, \alpha + \frac{1}{2}, \gamma)$ where $\alpha \ll -1$ and $\gamma > 1$. Note that for this choice of parameters, there exists quadratic transformations which might be useful
$$F\left(\alpha,\alpha+\frac{1}{2};\gamma,z^2\right) = (1\pm z)^{-2\alpha}F\left(2\alpha;\gamma-\frac{1}{2},2\gamma-1,\pm\frac{2z}{1\pm z}\right)$$
because it lets us express $F\left(\alpha,\alpha+\frac{1}{2};\gamma,z^2\right)$ using a Euler-type integral.

EDIT : Another way of doing it would be to prove $|F(\alpha,\beta;\gamma,z)| \geq 1$ similarly to this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299698/lower-bound-for-absolute-value-of-a-hypergeometric-function).